# No resource found that matches the given name button id

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I know this has got to be something little that I am missing, but I couldn't figure it out from other posts.  I have a simple Activity with a button that when pressed goes to another activity. As of right now I have two errors. The first is "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id+/Button03')" in the xml file,  and the second being "Button03 cannot be resolved or is not a field." in my Activity code.  I understand I need to be defined it somehow so that both can see and agree on it but I am not sure how.

Activity Code:

```
package com.JTInc.tag;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button aButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button03);
         aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        aButton.setText("You Clicked Me");
        }}); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my fragment code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.JTInc.tag.LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id+/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="@string/Button02" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All help is appreciated.  I know I am missing something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you xml file
Shouldn't `android:id="@id+/Button03"` be like this : `android:id="@+id/Button03"`

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it was something little.